# CSS Grid problem: Bottom elements end above top elements

Tags: html, css

I am finghting with CSS and trying to make everything is in its right place.

The thing is that bottom elements end up above the top ones, even if I set up a layout.

The HTML is like this:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 256px auto 256px;
  grid-template-rows: 50vh 50px auto 30vh;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "leftPic nav rightPic" "leftPic main rightPic" "leftFPic footer rightFPic";
}

.picture_container {
  width: 256px;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#left_aside {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-area: "leftPic";
  background-image: url("6354-1.jpg");
}

#left_bottom_aside {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30vh;
  grid-area: "leftFPic";
  background-image: url("6354-1-bottom.jpg");
}

#right_aside {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-area: "rightPic";
  background-image: url("6354-2.jpg");
}

#right_bottom_aside {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30vh;
  grid-area: "rightFPic";
  background-image: url("6354-2-bottom.jpg");
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgrey;
  height: 50vh;
}

.demoNav {
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: "nav";
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 50px;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.header>h1 {
  font-size: 50pt;
}

.header>h2 {
  font-size: 44pt;
}

.mainbody {
  grid-area: "main";
  align-self: center margin:0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
}

.final_footer {
  grid-area: "footer";
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <h1 id="header_title" class="title">WeinmanClub</h1>
    <h2 id="header_subtitle" class="subtitle">Movies. Movies Everywhere</h2>
    <nav id="header_demoNav" class="demoNav">
      <p>Here goes some menu options</p>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="left_aside" class="picture_container"></div>
  <main id="mainBody" class="mainBody">
    <section id="mainBody_aboutUs" class="nonImportant">
      <article id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne" class="nonImportantArticle">
        <h3 id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportantH3" class="unimportantH3">Rent and buy movies</h3>
        <p id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportant_p1" class="unimportantP">Hello there, we have movies for rental and sell. We also buy old movies because we are movie maniacs. <span>And now, some lore ipsum stuff</span>
        </p>
        <p id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportant_p2" class="unimportantP">Cras quis tristique risus. Fusce efficitur tellus eget vestibulum pretium. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec quam dolor, pharetra nec velit nec, dapibus interdum
          orci. Proin et imperdiet tortor, at dignissim neque. In malesuada lectus ut risus auctor, vitae molestie tellus gravida. Nam nisl ipsum, fringilla in feugiat sit amet, fringilla nec est. Sed maximus at magna ac cursus. Suspendisse blandit hendrerit
          orci, at hendrerit leo sollicitudin et. Cras bibendum tempor libero, et mollis ex pulvinar sit amet. Vivamus sit amet lorem tempus, finibus ipsum in, pretium turpis. In sollicitudin tincidunt dapibus. Maecenas efficitur enim sapien, congue vestibulum
          lacus tristique nec.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="mainBody_movies" class="important">
      <ul id="mainBody_movies_movieList" class="important_ul">
      </ul>
      <p id="mainBody_movies_p" class="important_p">Since this page was created for the API purpose, no roles are created. I could. However, I am doing that with React, Vue and Angular apps. Enjoy managing this web as if you were the owner.</p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <div id="right_aside" class="picture_container"></div>
  <div id="left_bottom_aside" class="picture_container"></div>
  <footer id="aboutMe" class="final_footer">
    Done by Weinman. No copyright, no copyleft. Pure copycenter.
    <a id="aboutMe_contributor" href='https://www.freepik.es/vectores/fondo'>Image done by starline - www.freepik.es</a>
  </footer>
  <div id="left_bottom_aside" class="picture_container"></div>
</body>
```

I know that the auto column and the auto row can give a headache, but this page changes content by making a REST request and displaying the information, son I cannot give a fixed height to main part (or maybe yes?).

On the other hand, the nav element fills the whole window, when it should be limited to the width between two pictures I am using.

I will keep trying, but any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I am adding an image of what would I want. Footer, BPICS 1 and 2 get above the rest, at the top.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZ1n.png "Template"

Comment: what do you want? please define in your question

Comment: grid-area: "footer"; - wrong, should be  grid-area: footer;

Comment: also making header height in vh - it depends on device heigth, not sure that its good idea to loose control on it. Maybe better do it in pixels but with @media query

Comment: @Sumitpatel the idea is having the contents surrounded by the sides with images. The main problem is that footer and bottom pictures cover the main part and side pictures. The footer problem can be because as Andreitazetdinov said, I quoted "footer" when I should not.

Comment: AndreiTazetdinov thanks, I didn't know that no quotes are required when assigning grid-areas. Now it is seen better, but footer and bottom pictures are above the rest of elements, yet.

I will be using @media and, for now, give absolute heights. Let's see if that's the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally, I just took a deep breath and redid the whole CSS, and a little bit the HTML.

It needs a few things yet, but the problem I had here is solved.

```js
/*
    requestAPI.js
    Manages REST requests and returns information to webpage
    Simplest API evaa!!!!
    Functions: Post, get, put, delete.
    Comments will be improved for using a proper, standard, code comments. Need to refresh that on google.
*/
//PostMethod -> Uses post request for getting information

const port = "3000";
const server = "http://localhost";


const getMethod = async function(reqType){
    let req;
    if(!reqType){
        req=server+":"+port;
    }
    else{
        req=`${server}:${port}/${reqType}`;
    }
    const response = await fetch(req,{mode:'cors'})

    return response.json();
}

//PutMethod -> Uses put request for sending information
const putMethod = function (reqType, newObj, id){
    if (!reqType||!newObj){
        console.error("Unable to do the request");
    }else{
        const req=`${server}:${port}/${reqType}/${id}`;
        fetch(req,
            {   mode:'cors', 
                method:'PUT', 
                headers:
                    {'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify(newObj)
            }
            ).then(response=>{
                if(response.ok===true){
                    response.json().then(res=>{
                        console.log(res);
                        return res;
                    }).catch(err=>console.error(err));
                } else{
                    console.error('Error. Status code: '+ response.status + ' '+ response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .catch(err=>{console.error(err);});
    }
}

//PostMethod -> Uses post request for getting information
const postMethod = function (reqType, newObj, id){
    if (!reqType||!newObj){
        console.error("Unable to do the request");
    } else {
        const req=`${server}:${port}/${reqType}/${id}`;
        fetch(req,
            {   mode:'cors', 
                method:'POST', 
                headers:
                    {'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify(newObj)
            }

        ).then(response=>
            {
                if(response.ok===true){
                    response.json().then(res=>{
                        console.log(res);
                        return res;
                    }).catch(err=>console.error(err));
                } else{
                    console.error('Error. Status code: '+ response.status + ' '+ response.statusText);
                }
            }
        ).catch(err=>{console.error(err);});
    }
}

//DeleteMethod -> Uses delete request for deleting information
const deleteMethod = function(reqType, id){
    if (!reqType||!id){
        console.error("Unable to do the request");
    } else {
        const req=server+':'+port+'/'+reqType+'/'+id;
        fetch(req,
            {   
                mode:'cors', 
                method:'DELETE', 
            }
        ).then(response=>{
            if(response.ok===true){
                response.json().then(res=>{
                    console.log(res);
                    return res;
                }).catch(err=>console.error(err));
            } else{
                console.error('Error. Status code: '+ response.status + ' '+ response.statusText);
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{console.error(err);});
    }
}
```

```css
/*General features*/
body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:200px auto 50px;
    grid-template-columns:100%;
    grid-template-areas: "header"
                         "main"
                         "footer";
    border:0;
    margin:0;
}

/*Header features*/
.header{
    grid-area: header;
    height: 200px;
    width: all;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:stretch;
    text-align: center;
}

.demoNav{
    text-align: center;
    align-self: bottom;
    background-color: darkgray;
    width:all;
    height:50px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 55pt;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.subtitle{
    font-size: 40pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.mainBody {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 258px auto 258px;
    grid-template-rows: 164px auto;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}

.gridfit {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
.mainBody > section {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}

.picture-main, .picture-small {
    width:256px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.picture-main {
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height: auto;
}

.picture-small{
    height: 164px;

}
#main-left {
    background-image: url("6354-1.jpg");
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

#main-right {
    background-image: url("6354-2.jpg");
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

#top-left {
    background-image: url("6354-1-top.jpg")
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
}

#top-right {
    background-image: url("6354-2-top.jpg")
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
/*Doesn't matter how long the page becomes. 
There will be side image*/

/*Main body features*/

/*Footer features*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your favourite Videoclub is here!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="requestAPI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let dataRaw;
            window.onload = async function(){
                const res = await getMethod();
                dataRaw = res;
                classifyInfo(res);
            }

            const classifyInfo = function(data){
                let content='';
                if(data['peliculas']&&data['clasificaciones']){
                    const movies=data['peliculas'];
                    const classes=data['clasificaciones'];
                    for(let i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
                        const clasMovies = searchInfo(movies, classes[i].nombre);
                        content+=`<li><h3>${classes[i].nombre}</h3><ul class=movielist>`;
                        for(let j=0;j<clasMovies.length;j++){
                            content+=`<li><div class='moviecard' id='movie_${clasMovies[j].id}'>
                                <h4>${clasMovies[j].nombre}<h4>
                                <p><span>Director:</span>${clasMovies[j].director}</p>
                                </div>
                                </li>`;
                        }
                        content+='</ul></li>';
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('mainBody_movies_movieList').innerHTML=content;
            }

            const searchInfo = function(data, term){
                const returnElement = data.filter(el=>el['clasificacion']==term);
                return returnElement;
            }

            const addElement = function(type, ...args){//nombre, director, clasificación
                try{
                    const oldElements = getElements(type);
                    const newElements=oldElements;
                    if(type==='clasificaciones'&&args.length===1){
                        newElements.push({'nombre':args[0], 'id':oldElements.length+1});
                        console.log(newElements);
                    } else if(type==='peliculas'&&args.length===3){                     
                        newElements.push({'nombre':args[0], 'director':args[1], 'clasificacion':args[2], 'id':oldElements.length+1});
                        console.log(newElements)
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Bad parameter pass.')
                    }               
                    const newList = dataRaw;
                    newList[type]=newElements;
                    classifyInfo(newList);
                    putMethod(type, newElements[newElements.length-1], newElements.length);
                    dataRaw=newList;
                }catch(err){console.error(err.message);}
            }

            const getElements = function(type){

                return dataRaw[type];
            }

            const getElementId = function(name, type){
                const elements = getElements(type);
                let id=-1;
                elements.forEach(el=> {
                    if(el.nombre==name){
                        id=el.id;
                    }
                });
                return id;
            }

            const deleteElement = function(name, type){
                const elements = getElements(type);
                const dEl = getElementId(name, type);
                if(dEl!=-1){
                    elements.splice(elements.findIndex(el=>el.id===dEl),1);
                    deleteMethod(type, dEl);
                    dataRaw[type]=elements;
                    classifyInfo(dataRaw);
                }
                else{
                    console.error('Element does not exist');
                }
            }

            const editElement = function(type, ...args){
                try{
                    const oldElements = getElements(type);
                    const newElements=oldElements;
                    const id = getElementId(args[0], type)
                    let newElement={};
                    if(type==='clasificaciones'&&args.length===2){
                        newElement={'id':id, 'nombre':args[1]} 
                    } else if(type==='peliculas'&&args.length===4){
                        console.log(args[0]);
                        console.log(args[1]);
                        newElement={'id':id,'nombre':args[1],'director':args[2], 'clasificacion':args[3]};          
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Bad parameter pass.')
                    }
                    console.log("Elemento editado");
                    console.log(newElement);
                    const index=newElements.findIndex(el=>el.id===id);
                    newElements[index]=newElement;              
                    const newList = dataRaw;
                    newList[type]=newElements;
                    classifyInfo(newList);
                    postMethod(type, newElements[index], id);
                    dataRaw=newList;
                }catch(err){console.error(err.message);}
            }
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header" class="header">
                <h1 id="header_title" class="title">WeinmanClub</h1>
                <h2 id="header_subtitle" class="subtitle">Movies. Movies Everywhere</h2>
            <nav id="header_demoNav" class="demoNav">
                <p>Here goes some urls to other pages. (same thing, but bootstrap, etc)</p>
                <!--When making stuff with bootstrap, jquery, etc, I will add links here-->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main id="mainBody" class="mainBody">
            <aside class="picture-small" id="top-left"></aside>
            <aside class="picture-main" id="main-left"></aside>
            <aside class="picture-small" id="top-right"></aside>
            <aside class="picture-main" id="main-right"></aside>
            <div class=gridfit>
                <section id="mainBody_aboutUs" class="nonImportant">
                    <article id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne" class="nonImportantArticle">
                        <h3 id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportantH3" class="unimportantH3">Rent and buy movies</h3>
                        <p id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportant_p1" class="unimportantP">Hello there, we have movies for rental and sell. We also buy old movies 
                        because we are movie maniacs. <span>And now, some lore ipsum stuff</span>
                        </p>
                        <p id="mainBody_aboutUs_articleOne_unimportant_p2" class="unimportantP">Cras quis tristique risus. Fusce efficitur tellus eget vestibulum pretium. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec quam dolor, pharetra nec velit nec, dapibus interdum orci. Proin et imperdiet tortor, at dignissim neque. In malesuada lectus ut risus auctor, vitae molestie tellus gravida. Nam nisl ipsum, fringilla in feugiat sit amet, fringilla nec est. Sed maximus at magna ac cursus. Suspendisse blandit hendrerit orci, at hendrerit leo sollicitudin et. Cras bibendum tempor libero, et mollis ex pulvinar sit amet. Vivamus sit amet lorem tempus, finibus ipsum in, pretium turpis. In sollicitudin tincidunt dapibus. Maecenas efficitur enim sapien, congue vestibulum lacus tristique nec.</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section id="mainBody_movies" class="important">
                    <ul id="mainBody_movies_movieList" class="important_ul">
                    </ul>
                    <p id="mainBody_movies_p" class="important_p">Since this page was created for the API purpose, no roles are created. I could. However, I am doing that with React, Vue and Angular apps. Enjoy managing this web as if you were the owner.</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer id="aboutMe" class="final_footer">
            Done by Weinman. No copyright, no copyleft. Pure copycenter.
            <a id="aboutMe_contributor" href='https://www.freepik.es/vectores/fondo'>Image done by starline - www.freepik.es</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: The result]

Now, gotta keep going and adding features. @AndreiTazetdinov, @Sumitpatel, thank you very much for your help!